# Reading extra characters while reading data into buffer

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I am writing a program to send data through pipes after reading it through a file. Sometimes the code works fine but for sometimes some extra characters are getting read. But the code works perfectly fine is `BUF_SIZE` is 1. I am guessing that I am reading some extra or garbage data but I cannot figure out where.

Extra Characters like:

> ÀêÒî

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

#define BUF_SIZE 512

int main(){
    int fd[2];
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    pipe(fd);
    switch(fork()){
       default:{
            close(fd[1]);
            fstream o;
            o.open("out.txt",fstream::trunc|fstream::out);
            int numread;
            while(1){
                numread=read(fd[0],buf,BUF_SIZE);
                if(numread<0) continue;
                if(numread==0) break;
                o<<buf;
            }
            o.close();
            close(fd[0]);
            wait(NULL);
            break;
       }
       case 0:
            close(fd[0]);
            ifstream inp("in.txt");
            char buf2[BUF_SIZE];
            while(inp){
                inp.read(buf2,BUF_SIZE);
                if(inp.gcount()!=0)
                    write(fd[1],buf2,inp.gcount());
            }
            inp.close();
            close(fd[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should fill your buffer with '\0' before the read.

Comment: I removed the C tag. This is C++.

Comment: Also if you are going to use the buffer as a character array you need to leave space for the null terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
char buf[BUF_SIZE];
```

into

```
char buf[BUF_SIZE+1];
```

and insert

```
buf[numread]=0;
```

before

```
o<<buf;
```

Otherwise buf contains garbage data behind the data received by `read`, and o << buf will copy that garbage data until it finds a `'\0'`